# ie 8 show itself as ie7 [CSS if condtion]?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

ie8  version on my computer , show itself as ie 7 when i use CSS IE CONDTION like

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello iam ie 7 :P ');</script>
<![endif]-->
```

but when i try it on another computer with ie8 its work normally , its possible to have any 
problem in my client website or this is ie problem ? 
(IE 8.0.7600.16385 )

Comment: Running in compatibility mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be problem with ur Internet Explorer Developer Tool so, use following to solve it,

```
press F12,
```

you can see the `Browser Mode : IE8`,

change it by clicking on it,

and select the appropriate menu,

```
Internet Explorer 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Msie8 has an option to act as ie7 -- if you press F12 you will get a debug window, and in the upper right corner of that window you should see various options about which version to act as. You can switch to ie8 there.

Answer (score 0):

can't tell for sure but I had an problem with ie8 some time ago that sounds pretty related to yours...

In my case I had to set the doctype of the html element in order to not run in compatibility mode where ie8 acts like it was ie7...

Just add something like that on the first line of your html and see if it works...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```